# Why do django queries to hot standby go slower than queries to master?

Tags: django, postgresql, django-orm

I have two servers, running postgres, setup to be master/replicator using hot standby.  When I make queries using django on the master server the queries take roughly half the time that the same queries on the replicated server take.  The servers are identical except that one is running a read/write database supplying WAL files and the other is running a read only database replicating from the WAL files.

If I make the queries on the replicated server to master the queries resolve twice as fast as they do if I make the queries directly to the local database.  Why is this?

I'm using a database router as described in the django documentation:

```
class DatabaseRouter:
    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        """
        Reads go to local host.
        """
        return 'default'

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        """
        Writes always go to master.
        """
        return 'write'

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        """
        Relations between objects are allowed if both objects are
        in the primary/replica pool.
        """
        db_list = ('default', 'write')
        if obj1._state.db in db_list and obj2._state.db in db_list:
            return True
        return None

    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
        """
        Migration handled by PostgreSQL
        """
        return None
```

And I have the databases settings in my settings file

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': NAME,
        'USER': USERNAME,
        'PASSWORD': PASSWORD,
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '5432',
    },
    'write': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': NAME,
        'USER': USERNAME,
        'PASSWORD': PASSWORD,
        'HOST': MASTER_IP,
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```